# The multi-part identifier "t.hperson" could not be bound

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

The below code is part of a query, which when I'm running I'm getting an error and I don't understand why (I bet this is really simple, but I can't get my head around it at the moment).

`t.hperson` is a column part of Tenant table and from my understanding when joining the `Property` table with `Tenant` I'm going to have all columns from tenant.

Then when joining with the subquery I get an error saying that

`Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 26
The multi-part identifier "t.hperson" could not be bound.`

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong or why it isn't seeing the hperson column from `Tenant` in my subquery.

```
from property p
    inner join tenant t on p.id = t.hprop
    inner join (select 
                  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY sequenceNr) AS IndexNr, tenant 
                from amendments where tenant = t.hperson) CurrentAmendment on 1 = 1
```

Can anyone please explain?

Comment: derived tables can't be correlated. You need `APPLY`

Comment: @MartinSmith I can see that the documentation about `APPLY` says that it is to be used with table valued functions. You're suggesting that I have to move my subquery into a table valued function?

Comment: No. It *can* be used with TVFs. It doesn't have to be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Derived tables can't be correlated. You need `APPLY`.

A rough equivalent to what you are attempting is

```
SELECT *
FROM   property p
       INNER JOIN tenant t
               ON p.id = t.hprop
       OUTER APPLY (SELECT ROW_NUMBER()OVER (ORDER BY sequenceNr) AS IndexNr,
                           a.tenant
                    FROM   amendments a
                    WHERE  a.tenant = t.hperson) CurrentAmendment
WHERE  1 = 1
```

Comment: Ok, this works but does this actually do something similar to a `LEFT JOIN`? I see that I can't add any `ON` conditions like in `JOIN`s, so this must mean I must continue to do my filtering in the `WHERE` part of the query, correct?

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu - Yes `OUTER APPLY` is analogous to outer join. Use `CROSS APPLY` for inner join. The filtering can be done in either of the `WHERE` clauses depending on the exact requirement.